# broadcast_rpc_address in 3 seed and 3 non-seed node cassandra cluster deployed on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

What should i set broadcast_rpc_address in 3 seed and 3 non-seed node cassandra cluster deployed on AWS?
***rpc address is set to wildcard 0.0.0.0***, 
Seed nodes launched using static ENI, 
Non seed nodes launched using ASG, 
ALL the nodes are launched in private subnet which are able to connect to internet using NAT gateway.
Added cassandra.yaml file which i am using

```yaml
cluster_name: 'Cassandra Cluster'
num_tokens: 256
hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer
permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
data_file_directories:
    - /var/lib/cassandra/data
commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
disk_failure_policy: stop
key_cache_size_in_mb:
key_cache_save_period: 14400
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0
row_cache_save_period: 0
saved_caches_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "seednode-A-IP,seednode-B-IP,seednode-C-IP"
concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32
trickle_fsync: false
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240
storage_port: 7000
ssl_storage_port: 7001
listen_address: 10.8.9.83
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
start_rpc: true
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
broadcast_rpc_address: NAT-GATEWAY-IP
rpc_port: 9160
rpc_keepalive: true
rpc_server_type: sync
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
incremental_backups: false
snapshot_before_compaction: false
auto_snapshot: true
tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000
column_index_size_in_kb: 64
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
cross_node_timeout: false
endpoint_snitch: Ec2Snitch
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1
request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler
server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    truststore: conf/.truststore
    truststore_password: cassandra
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
internode_compression: all
inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Okie, found the issue,
In cassandra versions 3.o and above cql uses 9042 for connection , after changing the LB listener port from 9160 to 9042, it worked